# Is there a software for writing story with a timeline and event and character

Tags: creative-writing, characters, software, timelines

I am looking for a software who have a timeline which can have event in it, items, character and a manuscript and if there is item and magic/skill it's even better

i can't afford to pay for using a software, i think campfire was a good option but it's 10 character max for free and for worldanvil i think i need to pay to put it in private and i try using kanka but i am not sure if it fit me well but itt has a lot of things i need

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As a fellow writer, I have the same issues with keeping organized and making sure the timeline fits. Here's a site I found, hopefully it works.
[WorldAnvil](https://www.worldanvil.com/author)

---

If I find any other sites that look like they would work, I'll come back and Send another link.

Comment: Sorry if i take time to awnser but witth world anvil do i need to pay to putt my project in private ?